# Java AES Padding Encryption Error While Transferring Video over TCP

Tags: java, encryption, tcp, cryptography, video-streaming

I am currently doing a project in Java to transfer a video file over TCP from a server to a client. The idea is the server will continue running and listen to incoming connection. Once there is an incoming connection from a client, the server will automatically send a video file to the client. (As of now the IP and file name is hard coded). The idea is so that the file can be copied and played at the same time

It is used locally and will automatically turn on VLC from the receiving computer to play the file being transferred. I have done the transfer part with no issues. The only problem comes up when I try to encrypt/decrypt the file. The code I have are below

**Runnable Thread FileTransfer Server**

```
public class FileTransferServer { 

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        //Initialize Sockets
        int i = 0;
        ServerSocket ssock = new ServerSocket(6012);

        while (true){
         ClientConnection CC;   
            CC = new ClientConnection(ssock.accept());
            Thread t = new Thread(CC);
            t.start();
        }        
    }
}
```

**Server Java File**

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import javax.crypto.CipherInputStream;
import javax.crypto.CipherOutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class ClientConnection implements Runnable 
{
private Socket socketPort;

public ClientConnection (Socket socketPort)
{
    this.socketPort = socketPort;
}

public void run()
{
    try {
        DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(socketPort.getInputStream());
        String videoName = input.readUTF();


        // automatically get local ip
        InetAddress IA = InetAddress.getByName("10.0.0.1"); 

        String key = "Maryhadonecat111";
        byte[] keyByte = key.getBytes("UTF-8");
        System.out.println(keyByte);
        System.out.println(keyByte.toString());

        //Specify the file
        File file = new File("D:\\Temp\\"+videoName);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis); 

        //Get socket's output stream
        OutputStream os = socketPort.getOutputStream();

        //Read File Contents into contents array 
        byte[] contents;
        long fileLength = file.length(); 
        long current = 0;
        long start = System.nanoTime();

        while(current!=fileLength){ 
            int size = 1000000;
            if(fileLength - current >= size)
                current += size;    
            else{ 
                size = (int)(fileLength - current); 
                current = fileLength;
            } 
            contents = new byte[size]; 
            bis.read(contents, 0, size); 
            //os.write(contents);                 
            os.write(CryptoTest1.doEncrypt(contents,keyByte));                   
            System.out.print("Sending file to "+ socketPort.getInetAddress().toString() +" " +(current*100)/fileLength+"% complete!\n");                
        }   

        os.flush(); 
        //File transfer done. Close the socket connection!
        socketPort.close();
        // ssock.close();
        System.out.println("File sent succesfully!");

    } catch (Exception e)
    {           
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    }
}
```

**Client Java File**

```
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import javax.crypto.CipherInputStream;
import javax.crypto.CipherOutputStream;

public class FileTransferClient { 

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    requestFile("10.0.0.1", "papa.avi");
}

public static void requestFile(String IP, String videoName) throws Exception{
    //Initialize socket
    Socket socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(IP), 6012);
    DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream( socket.getOutputStream());
    output.writeUTF(videoName);



    String key = "Maryhadonecat111";
    byte[] keyByte = key.getBytes("UTF-8");

    byte[] contents = new byte[1000000];
    //Initialize the FileOutputStream to the output file's full path.
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("D:\\Temp2\\"+videoName);
    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
    InputStream is = socket.getInputStream(); 

    System.out.println("Receiving File");
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\vlc.exe", "D:\\Temp2\\"+videoName);
    Process start = pb.start(); 
    //No of bytes read in one read() call
    int bytesRead = 0; 


    while((bytesRead=is.read(contents))!=-1){
        System.out.println("Bytes Received: " + bytesRead);

        contents = (CryptoTest1.doDecrypt(contents,keyByte));              
        bos.write(contents, 0, bytesRead); 

    }
    bos.flush(); 
    socket.close(); 

    System.out.println("File saved successfully!");
}
}
```

**CryptoTest1 Java File**

```
public class CryptoTest1
{
public static byte[] doEncrypt(byte[] msg, byte[] key) throws Exception {
    //prepare key
    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");

    //prepare cipher
    String cipherALG = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding"; // use your preferred algorithm 
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(cipherALG);
    String string = cipher.getAlgorithm();


    //as iv (Initial Vector) is only required for CBC mode
    if (string.contains("CBC")) {
        //IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv); 
        IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = cipher.getParameters().getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivParameterSpec);
    } else {
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec);
    }

    byte[] encMessage = cipher.doFinal(msg);        
    return encMessage;
}

public static byte[] doDecrypt(byte[] encMsgtoDec, byte[] key) throws Exception {
    //prepare key
    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");

    //prepare cipher
    String cipherALG = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding"; // use your preferred algorithm 
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(cipherALG);
    String string = cipher.getAlgorithm();

    //as iv (Initial Vector) is only required for CBC mode
    if (string.contains("CBC")) {
        //IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);   
        IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = cipher.getParameters().getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivParameterSpec);
    } else {
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec);
    }

    byte[] decMsg = cipher.doFinal(encMsgtoDec);        
    return decMsg;
}
}
```

**Issue**
I seem to have no issue encrypting the file and it is being sent over. The issue is decrypting the file. I can't seem to get it working. I've tried a lot of times and most of the errors comes down to "Padding Exception"

I am currently using ***AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding*** but I have tried the following

1. AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding
2. AES/CBC/NoPadding
3. AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding
4. AES/ECB/NoPadding

If I use padding, i will get an exception

> javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded

If I do not use padding, I will get an exception of

> javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length not multiple of 16 bytes.

Some other exception I have encountered while I was tinkering

> Missing Parameter
>   java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size
>   java.security.InvalidKeyException: Invalid AES key length: 64 bytes

I would like to ask if anyone of you would be willing to point me in a proper direction as to what I am doing wrong. I am still very new to Java, so please assume that I have very little knowledge. 
I have searched Stackoverflow for a long time and most encryption questions here are on text files, not on an actual video. If the encryption method I am using is not suitable for video, please let me know if there is a better one.

Comment: What is missing is any debugging such as hex displays of the key and IV for both encryption and decryption. Also there is an assumption that is `CBC` is not in the `cipherALG` string that CBC mode is not the default or that the default mode does not require padding..

Comment: Do not use ECB mode in new work and update legacy work ASAP, it is not secure, see [ECB mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_.28ECB.29), scroll down to the Penguin.

Answer (score 0):

The IV must be the same for both encryption and decryption. Generally a random IV is created on encryption and this must be provided to the decryption method. One way to handle this is to prefix the encrypted data with with the IV so on decryption it will be available.

## Notes:

1. AES is a block cipher so the input must be an exact multiple of the block size, this is generally accomplished with padding.
2. A bad padding error generally means that either the key, IV or encrypted data is incorrect, not that the padding is incorrect. The padding is incorrect because the decryption failed.